# Deleted ClearDB database through bluemix

Tags: database, ibm-cloud, cleardb

I just accidentally clicked on the delete button on the wrong database in bluemix. To be fair, on some views the database directly lines up with the instance, in others it doesn't.

So...
Who do I contact in order to get this recovered? I have sent an email to clearDB, but is there any more that I can do?

Thank you,
Matthew

Comment: Unfortunately no. Bluemix does not back up database instance. clearDB support might be able to help you recover the data. Good luck!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we can't do customer support](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Comment: Alright, thanks!!

I searched high and low to see if bluemix did any kind of backups or anything like that -- couldn't find any information anywhere (pretty much how it is when I search anything regarding bluemix actually)...

Comment: @user2455645 - I am sorry if you are unable to find the information that you need. The documentation is available at the following URL: https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/ In addition, if you have a suggestion for an enhancement to the UI (as a result of the issue that you encountered), you can submit an enhancement request at this URL: https://ibm-bluemix.uservoice.com/forums/311383-ibm-bluemix-ideas